# Are PIDs in python multiprocessing map guaranteed to have increasing order with respect to an iterable?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a list that I multi-process in chunks, let's say it's:

```py
l = range(100)
```

Let's assume I have 10 cpus (as in `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`). List `l` is divided into 10 chunks and then each process is responsible for each chunk through `foo` function:

```py
#pseudocode
def foo(chunk):
   pid = multiprocessing.current_process().pid
   for elem in chunk:
      pr_elem = process(elem)
      write pr_elem  in ('out' + str(pid)) file
```

```py
from more_itertools import divide

p = multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
p.map(foo, divide(multiprocessing.cpu_count(), l))
```

**Is the order of assigned PIDs always of increasing order with respect to iterable? Can I rely on this order and combine the results from `out[pid]` files and the order will match chunks (and hence elements) in list?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not. I have 8 logical cores, 4 physical cores. In the following code I create a pool of size 4 and invoke the `map` function specifying a *chunksize* of 1 so that a worker function only grabs one submitted task at a time. I also insert a `sleep` call immediately as the first instruction in my worker function to ensure that a given process does not process all the submitted tasks. This way I expect each of the 4 processes in the pool to process one submitted task each and that the print statements will occur in the order of submitted tasks.

```python
import multiprocessing
import time

def worker(x):
    time.sleep(1 + x)
    print(x, multiprocessing.current_process().pid)

def main():
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(4)
    pool.map(worker, range(4), chunksize=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
0 26632
1 15800
2 25916
3 30356
```

Comment: Thanks. I made a similar experiment few times but I have always received increasing order, hence the question

Comment: I ran this 5 or 6 times and *never* got them in increasing order, although it could certainly happen and should happen now and then. Perhaps there was something amiss in your experiment.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the order of assigned PIDs always of increasing order with respect to iterable?

No, it's not guaranteed.

You can use `enumerate` to have 2-tuples passed to your function, from which you can easily extract the order.

```
def foo(job):
   chunk_num, chunk = job
   # ...

n = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
with multiprocessing.Pool(n) as p:
    p.map(foo, enumerate(divide(n, l)))
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you briefly tell me why it is not guaranteed?

Comment: Nvm. I see it now